# Using a list as indexes to print certain elements from another list

Tags: c++, list, stl

I have this problem I am currently working on in C++.

You are given a list, L, and another list, P, containing integers sorted in ascending
order. The operation printLots(L,P) will print the elements in L that are in positions
specified by P. For instance, if P = 1, 3, 4, 6, the elements in positions 1, 3, 4, and 6
in L are printed. Write the procedure printLots(L,P). You may use only the public
STL container operations.

This is the code I have so far.

```
void printLots(list<int> L, list<int> P)
{
    list<int>::iterator myListIterator;

    for (myListIterator = P.begin();
        myListIterator != P.end();
         ++myListIterator)
    {
        //Not sure what to do here
    }
}
```

I know I could very easily print the contents of List P, but I'm not sure how to use it as indexes to print elements in those positions in List L. Based on my research, there is no way to directly index a list either so I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath sorry I'm not sure how that would be helpful. Could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that using a std::list is a requirement (not sure from your question) then as Karoly stated in the comments, use a counter to keep track of where you are in the linked list.

```
void printLots(const std::list<int>& L, const std::list<int>& P)
{
  std::list<int>::const_iterator it;
  for (it = P.begin(); it != P.end(); ++it) 
  {
    int indexRef = *it;
    // You never know
    if (indexRef < 0 || indexRef >= L.size()) continue;
    std::list<int>::const_iterator it2;
    int cntr = 0;
    for (it2 = L.begin(); it2 != L.end(); ++it2)
    {
      if (cntr == indexRef)
      {
        std::cout << *it2 << std::endl;
        break;
      }
      cntr++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't be very efficient though would it? Would a O(n) implementation be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::list<int> list_of_int;

void print( const list_of_int& L, const list_of_int& P )
{
  int p = 0;
  for ( list_of_int::const_iterator i = L.begin(), j = P.begin(); i != L.end(); ++i, ++p )
  {
    if ( p == *j )
    {
      std::cout << *i << ' ';
      ++j;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  list_of_int 
  L = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}
  , P = {2, 4, 5};
  print( L, P );
  return 0;
}
```

Try it [here](https://ideone.com/44oGiF).